# is mod_userdir preventing localhost http request?

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I'm using CPanel on CentOS 8 server. some of my php APIs need to make http request to other php API on the same server through `localhost`. I have already tried to make the call by using:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('method' => "GET", 'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$file = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/<path to api file from public_html>", false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

but I get `file not found error`. the point is that `mod_userdir` is turned off in the CPanel, and when I want to turn it on, it says: `Detected mod_ruid2 in use. Using both mod_userdir and mod_ruid2 is not a supported configuration.`
is the problem because of `mod_userdir` being turned off? if so, how to turn it on?

Comment: couldn't you just use `/home/account_name/public_html/path_to_file` ?

Comment: @HowardE yes, but then it prints the content of php file, it doesn't actually run the script as an API! why?!

Comment: That's what `file_get_contents` does

Comment: @HowardE you can also make http requests to APIs for example, what I also want.